# unmountable boot volume 0x000000ED on my laptop windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, boot, bsod

I am in a pickle.

I was unistalling some usless programs when my laptop died & when I turned it on I had unmountable boot volume 0x000000ED (the blue screen)

If I hit repair windows it goes to a black screen with the mouse (nothing else)

Now I tried f8 & then did command prompt but after it had gone to the loading files screen it had gone back to the blue screens with unmountable boot volume 0x000000ED.

I DL windows 7 repair but how do I get it to install when I cant get past the blue screen?

Does anyone know any other key codes when I turn it on or anything?

Am I screwed?

Help!

Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
Boot Windows DVD
repair mode
command prompt
chkdsk /f c:
if you have a d:
chkdsk /f d:
```

Comment: Can I boot with the usb?

Comment: I DL windows to a usb

Comment: I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

cybernard is right, I think but...

If you had some data to recover, I would suggest downloading a lightweight linux distro [puppylinux.org](http://puppylinux.org) or any other install it to a cd or usb drive [tuxboot.org](http://tuxboot.org) and attempt get your data off the disk.

I get a weird feeling you should try to backup before using chkdsk

forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2215622

happens all the time :-(

Comment: I did a back up of the data about 3-4 weeks so I want lose to much but it sucks. Thanks for the help